# Replacing a file into multiple folders/subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way in command prompt to take one file and copy it into another folder and its subdirectories based on its name?

I have an image named 5.jpg that has been put in a sub-folder that is in every folder in a directory.
I want to do a search inside of the folder (with the old image) and its sub-folders and replace all of the results with the new image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you completely. The following code will search for all occurences of 5.jpg in subfolders of C:\MyPath\ and replaces them with C:\NewImage\5.jpg. I did test it, so it should work.

FOR with parameter /R will help you here:

```
FOR /R C:\MyPath\ %%I IN (5.jpg) DO COPY /Y C:\NewImage\5.jpg %%~fI
```

If you want more information about what `FOR /R` does and what `%%~fI` means, have a look at `FOR /? | more` which gives nice explanations about the new Windows cmd possibilities that are used here.

Comment: Now that I look at it more closely, it looks like it works exactly how you say.
I need it to only add it into the subfolders that have the file in it because there are some that don't have the file.

Comment: seems to work if I put an asterisk in the parentheses like (*5.jpg)
Thanks

Comment: It gives error message: `%%I was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: I tried using this code on a huge documentation set where I needed to replace ~300 instances of a .js file with a new version of the file. The above code ended up copying the .js into *every* subfolder, regardless of whether it had the file. This resulted in in about 6000+ copies that I later had to mass delete.

Answer (score 25):

Probably there is one more (simpler) way.

Use the `replace` command:

```
replace C:\SourceFile.Txt C:\Some_Root_Folder_Which_Contains_Multiple_SubFolders /s
```

As the command itself says it just replaces the file, which already existed in sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

To do this work with several files, both paths are needed enclosed in quotes:

```
replace "C:\*.Txt" "C:\Some_Root_Folder_Which_Contains_Multiple_SubFolders" /s
```

The asterisk to make changes on all files with the ".txt" prefix.