# Replace all files in Folder with many sub folders with same name files with powershell

Tags: powershell

My problem is the following:

I repaired a bunch of `dwg` that were corrupted and i need to replace the corrupted ones with the repaired ones using power shell. They have the same name, the problem is that i acquired the files through the windows search tool, and i have them all in a single folder.

The original corrupted files exist in many sub folders. How do i copy all files from say folder

```
"d:\repaired" to "d:\original"
```

replacing each original files with its repaired one?
 I tried doing it with `xcopy` using the `/u`, but i also need a way to iterate through the sub-folders.

Comment: Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, i did it through command line. I found the answer here:
[Replacing a file into multiple folders/subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312310/replacing-a-file-into-multiple-folders-subdirectories)

I simply used something like this:

Replace C:\SomeFile.Txt C:\SomeRootFolder_ContainsMultipleSubFolders /s

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

```
 $files =  Get-ChildItem -path C:\files -Filter *.txt -Recurse
    
 foreach 
 ($file in $files) 
 {copy-item -path *.txt -destination $files -recurse -force}
```

Will find all files with a certain extension, then replace them with another file from a directory specified in the -path.

Comment: I tried this:

$files =  Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse

 foreach 
 ($file in $files) 
 {copy-item -path "C:\toReplace" *.txt -destination "C:\testRoot" $files -recurse -force}

and i get "a positional parameter cannot be found" error

Comment: Looks like that error is coming from your get-childitem. I presumed something in that script.