# Replace file.old with file.new in multiple subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to replace over 400 audio files, in just about as many sub-folders, with a updated format required by the program. It's the same file in each location but its how they require it for their xml file. I found several similar post, replacing files in multiple sub-directories like this one [Replacing a file into multiple folders/subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312310/replacing-a-file-into-multiple-folders-subdirectories) this I assumed would meet my needs.

I want to find all AR33.mp3 files in SFX'x folders, and replace with the new required AR33.wem my issue is as follows:

```
FOR /R C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX %%I IN (AR33.mp3) DO echo COPY /Y C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem %%~fI
```

This does the reverse and copies the file I want to overwrite, ar33.mp3, all over the folder structure in every folder where there shouldn't be any. but it does say 1 file copied after each entry.

(AR33) creates extension-less copies. adding (*AR33.mp3) does nothing, same with (*AR33.mp3 *) does nothing, even with "1 item copied" pointed out in the console. At this point I'm trying what I can to get this to work randomly doing stuff. Changing COPY to replace give a invalid switch -/y. Am I using the wrong "script" to do what I want? Because even changing one of the AR33.mp3 over to a .wem didn't see any change after replacing the line .mp3 to .wem. I assume I need to fix what its searching for and what its copying.

Updated bat:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX\" %%I IN (AR33.mp3) DO echo COPY /Y "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem" "%%~fI"
```

Output sample:

```
C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted>echo COPY /Y "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem" "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX\AAC0\ShipName__PASC045\isPlayer__False\AR33.mp3"
COPY /Y "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem" "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX\AAC0\ShipName__PASC045\isPlayer__False\AR33.mp3"
```

Comment: Please always double qoute your paths `FOR /R "C:\Users\folderpath\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX" %%I IN (AR33.mp3) DO COPY /Y "C:\Users\folderpath\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem" "%%~fI"` Also, are the files called `AR33.mp3` or do they contain `AR33.mp3` ?

Comment: i have "hide extension for known file types" turned off, so i assumed that was the files name needed and based off the other page. let me give it a test. :)

edit: leaving mp3 on the file, spams it all over the place.

Comment: Can you add the quotes as per my comment, then add `echo` before `copy` and show me some output when you run it.

Comment: `C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted>echo COPY /Y "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem" "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX\AAC1\ShipName__PGSC508\AR33"
COPY /Y "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem" "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX\AAC1\ShipName__PGSC508\AR33"` is all there is before it closes (i went ahead and edited the main post to show my full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to replace `.mp3` with `.wem` as well. For now you are simply copying the `.wem` file and naming it with a `.mp3` extension. So we could just rename the `.mp3`, then copy the `.wem` file to it.:

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\GoldenEye\SFX\" %%I in (*AR33.mp3) do (
    echo ren "%%~fI" "%%~nI.wem"
    echo copy /Y "C:\Users\trevo\Desktop\ProjectGoldenEYE\811converted\sfxwems\AR33.wem" "%%~dpnI.wem"
)
```

Please take **note** before continuing. The above will only echho the result, once you are happy that it does what you want, then only remove `echo from both strings in the code block.

It is also always a good idea to backup files before running a big `copy` process like this.

Comment: `\SFX" %%I in (*AR33.mp3) do` is what i changed it to. now, the bat, finds the `.mp3` files, renames them to `.wem` and then copies and overwrites the old file recently renamed, leaving only `AR33.wem`from my grasp of the function,  the size and modified dates match the new file i had made. this is exactly what i needed to happen. AR33.mp3 is the file that was to be replaced by the new AR33.wem.