# Replace files in multiple folders, whose name includes destination folder name

Tags: windows, command-line

I have very little experience with the command line and I'm trying to do something very complicated (to me).

I have a directory with A LOT of subfolders and files in them. All file names contain the parent folder name, e.g.:

```
Folder1  
  data_Folder1.csv 
  other_file_Folder1.csv 
Folder2
  data_Folder2.csv  
  other_file_Folder2.csv
```

In another folder (all in one directory), I have a new version of all the `data_FolderX.csv` files and I need to replace them in the original folders. I cannot give them another name because of later analyses. Is there a way to replace the files in the original folders with the new version, in the command line?

I tried this [Replacing a file into multiple folders/subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312310/replacing-a-file-into-multiple-folders-subdirectories) but didn't work for me. Given that I have many .csv files in the derectories, I don't want to replace them all, so I don't think I should do it based on the file extension. I would also like to note that the name "FolderX" contains several other `_`, so in principal, I want to replace the `.csv` file starting with `data` in the `FolderX`.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows REPLACE command.
Replace one file with another (both having the same filename).

When replacing in all subdirectories (/S ) the files in the source are matched against every subfolder, this is NOT a mirror, the files in each folder are matched separately.
The (/S ) subdirectories option cannot be combined with Add files (/A) or Restrict to Updating older (/U).
REPLACE will list all the files that are replaced. By default, only files that already exist in the destination will be replaced.
You cannot use REPLACE to update any file which has a hidden or system attribute set.
The path to the destination folder must NOT include a trailing backslash.

EXAMPLES

Syntax:

```
replace C:\SourceFile.rtf  C:\Some_Folder_Which_Contains_SubFolders  /s /r /u
```

Command:

```
replace "D:\Downloads\newfile\testfile.rtf" "D:\Downloads\destinationfolder" /s /r /u
```

Output:

```
Replacing D:\Downloads\destinationfolder\testfile.rtf
Replacing D:\Downloads\destinationfolder\testfolder\testfile.rtf
Replacing D:\Downloads\destinationfolder\testfolder\folder2\testfile.rtf
Replacing D:\Downloads\destinationfolder\testfolder\folder2\folder4\testfile.rtf
Replacing D:\Downloads\destinationfolder\testfolder\folder2\folder4\folder5\testfile.rtf
Replacing D:\Downloads\destinationfolder\testfolder\folder3\testfile.rtf
```